# Validate object attribute in manager in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a manager in which I have

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    TYPE_PENDING = 1

    def pending():
        return self.filter(type=self.TYPE_PENDING)
```

Now I can always get a queryset of pending objects.

But can I also do something to check if an object is pending?

I can of course use `if object.type == MyManager.TYPE_PENDING:` but can I do something in the manager, so I don't have to call `MyManager.TYPE_PENDING` outside the manager but instead create a function like

```
def is_pending():
    return self.type == self.TYPE_PENDING
```

or something like that.

I could also do something like `if object in Model.objects.pending():` but doesn't it have bad performance since it loads the entire queryset?

## Edit

If I have two managers `PackageManager` and `StateManager` related to models `Package` and `State`, resp.

```
class PackageManager(models.Manager):
    def delivered(self):
        return self.filter(current_state__type=1)

class StateManager(models.Manager):
    def delivered(self):
        return self.filter(type=self.model.TYPE_DELIVERED)
```

I have my choices (`TYPE_DELIVERED` etc.) defined in `State`. Can I in `PackageManager` replace `1` with something telling that it should be `TYPE_DELIVERED`?

I know I can write `current_state__type=State.TYPE_DELIVERED` but it causes a circular import if I should import managers into models and models into managers.

Can I utilize that I can get a State queryset filtering for all delivered?

I mean if I can do something like

```
class PackageManager(models.Manager):
    def delivered(self):
        return self.filter(current_state__type=StateManager.model.TYPE_DELIVERED)
```

Comment: your `pending` needs a `self` as an argument. But even so, it would be incorrect to use it in `return self.type == self.TYPE_PENDING`. `self` does not point to the model object, but to the manager.

Comment: A manager should host those methods/properties relevant to a queryset (i.e. a collection of records). The model, as @dgel has pointed out correctly, should host those methods/properties relevant to a single record (e.g. your condition on type)

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be more appropriate to define `TYPE_PENDING` in the model itself:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    TYPE_PENDING = 1
    ...

    @property
    def is_pending(self):
        return self.type == self.TYPE_PENDING

    objects = MyManager()

...

class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def pending():
        return self.filter(type=self.model.TYPE_PENDING)
```

Comment: are you sure about `type == self.TYPE_PENDING` ? Where is `type` defined? It's a model field, so it should be reached via `self.type`, I think

Comment: I didn't know I could access the model in which the manager was used with self.model. Thank you :D

Comment: [You should create a new question for your follow-up (you can include a link to this question)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)- otherwise this will become a complicated mess of edits.